# Use string to call function in class

Tags: python, class

I have a string which I want to use to call a function in a class.

```
class TimeValue:
    def __init__(self, *args):
        self.args = args
    def PV(self):
        FV,r,n  = self.args
        return f"$ {FV/(1+(r/100))**(n):.3f}"
        
    def FV(self):
        PV,r,n  = self.args
        return f"$ {PV*(1+(r/100))**(n):.3f}"
    def Annuity(self):
        C,r,n  = self.args
        return f"$ {(C/(r/100)) * (1-(1/(1+(r/100)) ** (n-1))):.3f}"
    def Perpetuity():
        pass

inv_comp = input("Enter a desired investment computation (PV, FV, Annuity, Perpetuity) ")
obj = TimeValue(*req_values)
###------------###
print(obj.locals()["inv_comp"]())
###------------###
```

The problem here is that python wants to call `locals()` which is not a function in the class.
How can I call the functions in the class using `inv_comp` directly?

Comment: Even though it's possible - this code smells. Consider redesigning

Comment: Theres much more to the code to make is cleaner, I took only the helpful parts.

Answer (score 2):

Use `getattr`:

```
getattr(obj, inv_comp)()
```

Note that you want to use the *variable* `inv_comp`, not the *string literal* `"inv_comp"`.

The `getattr` function takes a string (which is going to be something like `"PV"` or whatever the user entered), and returns an attribute in `obj` matching that name, so:

```
getattr(obj, "PV")
```

is equivalent to:

```
obj.PV
```

If `inv_comp` isn't the name of an existing attribute, `AttributeError` will be raised, exactly like if you typo'd the name of an attribute in your code.